# Write a JSON method that will receive a JSON string representing an array of integers, return Arraylist of integers from the array?

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist

I need to write a JSON method that will receive a JSON string representing an array of integer (e.g."[100,500,300,200,400]") and will return an ArrayList of integers containing the integers in the JSON array string.

I kind of have it down, but I'm still having troubles. Should I even be doing a loop?

```
ArrayList<Integer> ListInt;
public  ArrayList<Integer> createArrayListofIntegersFromJSONString(String jsonString) throws JSONException {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonString.size(); i++) {
             ArrayList[i] = jsonString[i];
    return ArrayList;
    }
```

Comment: Neither the `ArrayList` or the `String` are arrays, so how does the "access using index" concept come into picture? Also, you will need a JSON parser which will parse your JSON string into something(JSON array probably) that can be converted to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a library like Jackson or Gson, preferably to what you're doing. anyway, if you don't care about input validation and the like, you can try using regular expressions:

```
private static final Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");

public static List<Integer> list(String pseudoJson) {
    Matcher matcher = numberPattern.matcher(pseudoJson);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(matcher.find()) {
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1)));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String json = "[ 100, 500, 300, 200, 400 ]";

    System.out.println(">>>" + list(json));
}
```